# Jasmine/Angular: Cannot read property 'patchValue' of undefined (component testing)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

In my unit test, I am testing to see if my service is being called.  I have a function called loadUser(). This function uses a service getData, to retrive all of the users from a url. Then, it loads the userID and that specific user's information (name, lastname, etc) into a form. From here, the user is allowed to edit their credentials. This function uses patchValue to display the data to the correct form field. Now I am only trying to test if my service, getData is called and that is it. When running my test, I receive this error:  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'patchValue' of undefined`. I would like for my test to say that getData has been called. Here is my test, and below that my function (for brevity, I only posted necessary code). I posted my setup because maybe I am missing something there?

Spec:

```
    fdescribe('User Component', () => {
    let httpService: HttpService;
    let userComponent: UserComponent
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserComponent>
    let debugElement: DebugElement;

beforeEach(async() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        UserComponent, 
      ],
      imports: [HttpModule, FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule],
      providers: [
          HttpService
      ],
  }).compileComponents();
});

beforeEach(() => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
     userComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
     debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
     httpService = debugElement.injector.get(HttpService);

fit('should have getUsers() call the service GetData()', inject([HttpService], fakeAsync((httpService) => {
    let url = AppConfig.URL_UserById'

    let getDataSpy= spyOn(httpService,'getData').and.returnValue(Observable.of(url));
        userComponent.loadUser();
     expect(getDataSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
   })))
})
```

Component:

```
  loadUser() {
this.httpService.getData(AppConfig.URL_UserById + "?UserID=" + this.userId)
  .catch((error: Response | any) => {
    this.showAlertWindow(this.exceptionMessage);
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
  })
  .subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.frmUser.patchValue({

      FirstName: res.FirstName,
      MiddleName: res.MiddleName,
      EmailAddress: res.EmailAddress,
      LastName: res.LastName

    });
    this.setUserAccess(res.UserAccessDetail)

  });
```

Now, if I comment out the line `this.frmUser.patchValue){FirstName...}`, the test passes and successfully checks if getData() is called. So I am guessing I need to initiate patchValueor something along those lines. Thank you.

Comment: Again, read the error message. It says "Cannot read property 'patchValue' of undefined". So, when trying to invoke `this.frmUser.patchValue()`, it can't, because `this.frmUser`is undefined. Which means that you haven't initialized it.

Comment: I initialize the form by `let form = userComponent.frmUser`  and putting this into my it block. But that just creates a variable with the form. Do I need to pass this value in my test so that it is not undefined?

Comment: Including `userComponent.ngOnInit()` solved the problem. This is because in my ngOnInit(), I create my user form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution to the problem. In my ngOnInit component, I create my user form. All I needed to do was do `userComponent.ngOnInit()` and the test passed.

full code for working test:

```
fit('should have getUsers() call the service GetData()', inject([HttpService], fakeAsync((httpService) => {

    let url = AppConfig.URL_UserById + "?UserID=" + this.userId

    let getDataSpy= spyOn(httpService, 'getData').and.returnValue(Observable.of(url));

   userComponent.ngOnInit();
   userComponent.loadUser();

        expect(getDataSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

   })))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding it to my

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.myForm.patchValue({
      username: this.AUTH_USER.username
    })
}
```

Solved the issue: Keep in mind I have AUTH_USER declared with the initial values of the logged in user.